# Get the height of items in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-runtime, windows-store, win-universal-app

I have an ListBox with a few items. I tried to calculate the height of the ListBox, so that the items are fitting well in the ListBox. But I can't access the height of each listBoxItem, to calculate the height.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myList}}" Height="100" Width="250">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

.

```
//Code Behind
public class ItemList : ObservableCollection<Items>
    {
        public ItemList() : base()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        private string name;
        private string description;

        public Items(string Name, string Description)
        {
            this.name = Name;
            this.description = Description;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return description; }
            set { description = value; }
        }
    }

public App1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            products = new List<Items>();
            products.Add(new Items("Product1", "This is Product1"));
            products.Add(new Items("Product2", "This is Product2"));
            products.Add(new Items("Product3", "This is Product3"));
            products.Add(new Items("Product4", "This is Product4"));

            listBox.ItemsSource = products;

            listBox.Height = listBox.Items.Count * ListBoxItem.Height;
        }
```

So, I am searching the "ListBoxItem.Height", but how I can access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height for each item inside the listbox like this,

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox"  Height="100" Width="250">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
```

Comment: This sets the height, but as the question asks - how do you *get the height'??

Comment: @RobertAchmann You will get to know the height when you set itself.

Comment: Please, can you show how you got the height in the manner you've explained. I'm not following you.

Comment: @RobertAchmann You must be knowing the height when you set the height

Comment: Yes, when the View is built, but now the user is interacting and things have changed. I no longer know what is in the list...so my question still stands. Is it expected that I keep track of each item's height on each listbox change, or do you know of a way to calculate item height in listbox 'X'

Comment: It's an old question, but one of the ways how to do this is to create TextBlock and copy the content of binded one. Then you simply get the actuall hight of it.